# Use of undeclared type 'Object'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

This is so weird. Normally I could understand a class not being declared, but this is claiming the Object class itself is not declared. NSObject works, but the way my project is setup I need it to be a pure Swift Object. My class header looks like this:

```
 import UIKit
 import Foundation
 class Person: Object {
```

I know foundation isn't really necessary, I just added it because I wasn't sure if that was causing me issues. The issue is occurring in both actual projects and playgrounds as well as in Xcode 6 and the latest Xcode 7 beta with Swift 2.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just remove `: Object`. Pure Swift classes don't need to inherit from a superclass

Comment: Thank you! I'm not allowed to accept this for another 9 minutes, but I will when it gets there. I do wonder why you aren't explicitly allowed to do that. though.

Comment: You can't do it because there is no `Object` class to inherit from. As you noted, there is an `NSObject` class. But there is no Swift type called `Object`.

Answer (score 16):

**if you are using Realm then import**

```
import RealmSwift
```

Complete syntax of class.

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class User: Object {

}
```

If you face any difficulty to implement this code. Watch below video
Link: https://youtu.be/5Z8tBKwk6-c

Answer (score 4):

Pure Swift object doesn't inherit from a superclass:

`class Person {}`

You can read [Classes and Structures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID83)

Answer (score 0):

```
For RealmSwift

import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Note: Object{
    @objc dynamic var id = 0
    @objc dynamic var title = ""
    @objc dynamic var created = Date()
    @objc dynamic var text = ""
    
    override static func primaryKey() -> `enter code here`String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.