# Realm Cannot invoke 'add' with an argument list of type '(Person)'

Tags: swift, realm, swift2

This error is so frustrating. I'm just trying to add an object to my Realm database and I have gotten to the point of just copying and pasting example code and it will not work. So I have an add person method that does this:

```
func addPerson(person person:Person){
    realm.beginWrite()
    realm.add(person)
    realm.commitWrite()
}
```

And the realm variable is stored like this in the class header:

```
private var realm:Realm
```

Being initialized in the `init()` method as such:

```
realm = Realm()
```

My actual person class looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class Person {
var name:String?
var relation: Relations?
var title: String?
var importance:Double?
var events:Array<Event>?
var image:UIImage?
init(name:String,relation:Relations?,events:Array<Event>?,image:UIImage?){
    self.relation = relation
    if relation != nil{
        self.title = relation!.title
        self.importance = relation!.importance
    }
    else{
        self.title = nil
        self.importance = nil
    }
    self.events = events
    self.image = image
    self.name = name
}

init() {

}
}
```

The error is so frustrating because it seems like the Person class does not conform to the Object superclass, but in reality, that's the only option

Comment: Have you tried making `Person` a subclass of `Object`? In the Realm documentation, it states that "you define your model classes by subclassing Object…" (see https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Object.html)

Comment: @aaplmath I would have, but as you can see from my previous question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31477613/use-of-undeclared-type-object) I was having trouble with that.

Comment: I looked at that question. It seems to me that `Object` is a Realm class as opposed to a pure Swift class, so it is actually necessary in order to allow the class to act as a model. In other words, it's not like subclassing `NSObject`, but rather a custom class defined by Realm.

Comment: don't forget to add "import RealmSwift" at the top as well, aaplmath is correct

Comment: @aaplmath wow you're right. That is the worst naming convention I think I have ever seen. Thanks for the help! If either of you want credit, (aaplmath especially because you answered first), feel free to answer and I can accept it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a summary of what I said in the comments:

Use `Object` as a subclass as it is necessary for a class to be a model in Realm.

Comment: How the hell could they name it "Object" it is so misleading.